# Problem with if-clause in Spinner Android

Tags: android, if-statement, spinner

I am developing a small Android App. Now I have a problem and dont know why this is...
I wanted to build a own Calendar-Function to insert dates.
I can choose date and time via date- and time-pickers. now i wanted to add a spinner where one can choose between different durations for the date....
but the if-clause within the spinner only works if i choose a second time and another item than i chose the first time

Here is part of my code:
            duration.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

```
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int position, long l) {

                if(av.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("10 Minuten")){
                    dateInMS2 = (dateInMS1 + 600000);
                }
                else if(av.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("30 Minuten")){
                    dateInMS2 = (dateInMS1 + 1800000);
                }
                else if(av.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("1 Stunde")){
                    dateInMS2 = (dateInMS1 + (1 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                }
                else if(av.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("2 Stunden")){
                    dateInMS2 = (dateInMS1 + (2 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                }
                else if(av.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("3 Stunden")){
                    dateInMS2 = (dateInMS1 + (3 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                }
                else if(av.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("4 Stunden")){
                    dateInMS2 = (dateInMS1 + (4 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                }
                else if(av.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("5 Stunden")){
                    dateInMS2 = (dateInMS1 + (5 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                }
                else if(av.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("6 Stunden")){
                    dateInMS2 = (dateInMS1 + (6 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                }
                else if(av.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("ganztägig")){
                    dateInMS2 = (dateInMS1 + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                }
                else{
                    dateInMS2 = (d1.getTime() + (1 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                }

            }


            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> av) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //dateInMS2 = (d1.getTime() + (1 * 60 * 60 * 1000));                    
            }

        });
```

This is within the onClick-Method of the button I touch to insert the date.....
dateInMS1 is the time of the time-picker in milliseconds. dateInMs2 is the time-picker-time plus the milliseconds for the duration i chose.

Can anyone help me?!

Answer (score 0):

I do not complety understand what you mean by :

> but the if-clause within the spinner only works if i choose a second time and another item than i chose the first time

But i geuss why it's not working is because you create the onclicklistener within the code of your buttons on click method. So the spinner will only react to a selected item when you have already clicked the button. So you should call this part.

`duration.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){`

and all code after that in the oncreate of your activity and then it will work!

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks... I got the problem already by myself... no I have to see wether I can manage to put it outside the onClick()-Method.